# Attempt to register a cell class which is not a subclass of UICollectionViewCell. Huh?

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I'm attempting to create my first UICollectionView with *sections*.

**Scenario:**  a UIViewController with a UICollectionView member.

**Goal:** To register both the UICollectionViewCell & UICollectionReusableView (header) cell.

**Problem:** I got a runtime error that the header is NOT a UICollectionReusableView.

```
@IBOutlet weak var gCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var headerView: UICollectionReusableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
// Cell:
gCollectionView.registerClass(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: kCellID)


// Header:
gCollectionView.registerClass(UICollectionReusableView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: kHeaderID)
}
```

[image]
[image]

> ...reason: 'attempt to register a cell class which is not a subclass of
>   UICollectionViewCell (UICollectionReusableView)'

**Question:** I can't see anything wrong here, the header is treated like the cell, but it's flagged for not being a true UICollectionReusableView.  Why?

---

When I commented out the registration:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Cell:
    //    gCollectionView.registerClass(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: kCellID)


        // Header:
 //       gCollectionView.registerClass(UICollectionReusableView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: kHeaderID)

    }
```

... my app (minus header which isn't coded yet) WORKS.  --- don't I need to register the cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to register the class if the prototype is designed in InterfaceBuilder. Just give it an reuse identifier there.

Comment: thank you so much .... I was struggling from long time to load custom cell content.

Answer (score 3):

I also received this error:

```
Thread 1: Exception: "attempt to register a cell class which is not a subclass of UICollectionViewCell (UICollectionView)"
```

This is what my Collection view looked like while broken:

```
fileprivate let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.register(UICollectionView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        return cv
    }()
```

My collection view had a slight issue, I changed it to this and it compiles:

```
fileprivate let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        return cv
    }()
```

Notice the small change where my mistake was:

- I had UICollectionView.self
- Instead, it should have been UICollectionViewCell.self